# SSRS IIF Syntax with Multiple Datasets

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, expression, iif

I have a report with 2 data sets and would like to perform a SUM operation in a textbox expression. The problem arises when I want to perform an IIF in the sum since I only want a particular category of values summed.

I would like to get a sum of all the "Good" ranking values from the dsRetrieveCustomerAssetScores dataset. Please note there is more than one data set in the report, so I need to specify the scope when using the aggregate function. Below is the code I've tried (along with other permutations).

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!ranking.Value,"Good",1,0), "dsRetrieveCustomerAssetScores")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happened when you tried that code?

Answer (score 3):

You may have more than one dataset in your **report**, but I don't think it's possible to have more than one dataset per **tablix**. (Subreports within the tablix may be bound to a different dataset, but anywhere within the subreport will only be accessing that other dataset.)

The scope specified within aggregation formulas is normally related to groups within the tablix, not the datasources.

So, the code:

```
=Sum(iif(Fields!ranking.Value,"Good",1,0))
```

- should work within your tablix, as long as that tablix is accessing the dsRetrieveCustomerAssetScores dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I get this error now: "The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox4’ uses an aggregate expression without a scope.  A scope is required for all aggregates used outside of a data region unless the report contains exactly one dataset. The odd thing is I can do things like this: =Count(Fields!ranking.Value, "dsRetrieveCustomerAssetScores") That returns a value, so the report has access to the underlying data. I just want to filter what gets aggregated. Seems to me the syntax is weird - why can't you use a IIF inside the aggregate function?

Comment: OK, I hadn't considered the possibility that you were accessing that summary outside a data region. You still haven't told me what happened when you tried `=Sum(iif(Fields!ranking.Value,"Good",1,0), "dsRetrieveCustomerAssetScores")`.

Comment: Thanks for helping. When I use that syntax the following error occurs: The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox4.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: I've just realised that the syntax for `iif` isn't quite right - what happens if you try `=Sum(iif(Fields!ranking.Value="Good",1,0), "dsRetrieveCustomerAssetScores")` ? (I don't have access to an instance of SSRS right now.)

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for the help figuring out the syntax!